# Javascript Function to Open a URL on the main page or new window

Tags: javascript

I am using some javascript in an iframe that is located on my website's frontpage. There is a slide function so that when a user slides an image it will open up a link to another site but at the moment its opening the link within the iframe so it looks really funny.

This is the js code im using atm:

```
    var unlock = function()
{
    //$("#gfx").animate({backgroundPosition: '0 40'}, 400, '', function()
    //{
        $("#gfx-bottom").animate({bottom: -100}, 300);
        $("#gfx-top").animate({top: -100}, 300, '', function()
        {});    
        $("#iphone-inside").fadeOut("normal", function(){window.location="http://www.urlimtryingtolinkto.com";});                                 
    //});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use window.top.

```
var unlock = function()
{
    //$("#gfx").animate({backgroundPosition: '0 40'}, 400, '', function()
    //{
        $("#gfx-bottom").animate({bottom: -100}, 300);
        $("#gfx-top").animate({top: -100}, 300, '', function()
        {});    
        $("#iphone-inside").fadeOut("normal", function(){window.top.location="http://www.urlimtryingtolinkto.com";});                                 
//});
```

Comment: @FizRaqim My friend, Accept this answer if it worked for you. Just saying "you are the best" is not enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

For a new window, use [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)

```
var unlock = function()
{
    //$("#gfx").animate({backgroundPosition: '0 40'}, 400, '', function()
    //{
        $("#gfx-bottom").animate({bottom: -100}, 300);
        $("#gfx-top").animate({top: -100}, 300, '', function()
        {});    
        $("#iphone-inside").fadeOut("normal", function(){window.open("http://www.urlimtryingtolinkto.com");});                                 
    //});
```

Comment: @FizRaqim My friend, Accept this answer if it worked for you. Just saying "you are the best" is not enough :-)